# Column width in finder list view option

Tags: finder, macos

How can I keep the column width in the list view option of finder?

Every time I reopen a folder I have to readjust the width of the columns so I can tell what files are in the folder. It is most annoying.
Option drag doesn't work.

Comment: I've noticed the only folder it just can't remember seems to be the desktop.  Other folders seem to remember exactly where the columns were!  The desktop is my main place to keep clean, kind of like an actual desktop it contains stuff I need to deal with, so it's really a big hassle to have to resize every time.  Someone mentioned deleting the com.apple.finder prefs file and I tried that and it doesn't work.  I'm on OS 10.13.3